# How to build and map an entity class that derives from a system class with properties and methods that are not virtual?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have following model.

```
public class DataValue : Collection<DataValue>
{
  private List<DataValue> _values;
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Value { get; set; }

  protected override void InsertItem(int index, DataValue item)
  {
    base.InsertItem(index, item);
    this._values.Add(item._value);
  }
}
```

The model inherits Collection class. This is needed on my domain model but it is not crucial for NHibernate. So every instance of this class is a one line in the database but it can contain other DataValues that are initialized by other parts of the software.
I map it like this (Fluent)

```
public DataValueMap()
{
  Id(x => x.Id);
  Map(x => x.Value);
}
```

Now, when NHibernate tries to create the proxy class, it throws following error

```
NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException: NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException:
 The following types may not be used as proxies:
 DataValue: method get_Count should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
 DataValue: method get_Item should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
 DataValue: method set_Item should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
 DataValue: method Add should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
 etc... basically all the Collection methods and properties
```

This of course is caused by the fact that Collection methods and properties are not virtual. How should I fix this problem?

- DataValue should be lazy loadable so disabling LazyLoad is not an option.
- I could implement IList and not inherit Collection but that would clutter the class and inheriting a Collection is in my opinion cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime proxies are involved you have to have all public properties and methods marked as virtual.  This is because in order to return a proxy of a mapped class, nhibernate inherits a proxy object from your object, and adds the lazy loading magic to it.  Therefore, each public property on a mapped class to be lazy loaded must be virtual.  Since you cannot control the properties you are directly inheriting from Collection (i am not sure of the surrounding code reasons why you are doing this), you will need to consider re-arranging your code to omit that requirement, or possibly try inheriting from ICollection and implementing the methods directly instead of inheriting directly from Collection (probably the best way).

Comment: I ended up implementing it like David described in this answer. Firo's approach could also be feasible in some cases. I implemented IList and had private peroperty of type Collection.

Answer (score 0):

the check can be disabled:

```
public class CustomProxyFactoryFactory : IProxyFactoryFactory
{
    NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory internalfactory = ...;

    public IProxyFactory BuildProxyFactory()
    {
        return internalfactory.BuildProxyFactory();
    }

    public bool IsInstrumented(Type entityClass)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool IsProxy(object entity)
    {
        return (entity is INHibernateProxy);
    }     

    public IProxyValidator ProxyValidator
    {
        get { return new CustomProxyValidator(); }
    }
}

public class CustomProxyValidator : DynProxyTypeValidator
{
    private const bool iDontCare = true;

    protected override bool CheckMethodIsVirtual(Type type)
    {
        return iDontCare;
    }
}
```

using fluentnhibernate

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(xxxConfiguration.Standard
        .ProxyFactoryFactory<CustomProxyFactoryFactory>())
```

I'm not sure if castle can handle non virtual methods